# python df to html result is not table format

Tags: python, html, django, dataframe, request

I am trying to send some values(server_data) to a basic webpage and want to see as a table form.
I reformated my values as a Dataframe and converted them to html format.
But when I display my table, I just see html codes, not table form.
What am I missing?

Python code:

```
def vip_result(request):  (---)
        server_data{"SERVER_IP":result1,"PORT":result2,"SERV.STATE":result3,"OPR. STATE":result4}
        df=pandas.DataFrame(server_data)
        df=df.to_html
        return render(request, 'vip_result.html', {"df": df})
```

Html site:(vip_result.html)

```
{{df}}
```

Result page`

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead> <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th></th> <th>SERVER IP</th>
    <th>PORT</th>
    <th>SERV.STATE</th>
    <th>OPR. STATE</th>
</tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <th>0</th> <td>10.6.87.17</td> <td>7777</td> <td>UP</td> <td>ENABLED</td> </tr> <tr> <th>1</th> <td>10.6.87.18</td> <td>7777</td> <td>UP</td> <td>ENABLED</td> </tr> <tr> <th>2</th> <td>10.6.87.21</td> <td>7777</td> <td>UP</td> <td>ENABLED</td> </tr> <tr> <th>3</th> <td>10.6.87.21</td> <td>7780</td> <td>UP</td> <td>ENABLED</td> </tr> <tr> <th>4</th> <td>10.6.87.23</td> <td>7781</td> <td>UP</td> <td>ENABLED</td> </tr> <tr> <th>5</th> <td>10.6.87.23</td> <td>7783</td> <td>UP</td> <td>ENABLED</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`:
```

[Result page that I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyJHe.png)

Comment: Please add your ``import``-statements. Where does the function ``render`` come from?

Comment: @Alperino I just wanted you to focus Dateframe section.@Hayden's answer solved my problem.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Django to trust the content

```
{{df | safe}}
```

This tells Django it can put the HTML in as HTML.

Comment: Thank you @Hayden it worked.Now I can see my table at server response :)

Comment: @Kaan could you accept the answer in that case for future reference? Thanks!